# Unlock 2013 Moto X

Tags: moto-x

I currently have a 2013 Moto X that I purchased from republic wireless which uses Sprint's network (USA).  I would like to leave this prepaid service to join Verizon.  I took my phone to Verizon today and they said that they couldn't add the phone to their network.  Does anyone know how to unlock my phone for use on Verizon's network.

I was about to use [this](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/standalone/bootloader/unlock-your-device-b) unlocking program on Motorola's website, but I'm not sure if this will be useful for what I am trying to do.

Comment: I would doubt the radio hardware is compatible, but even if it was, Verizon generally doesn't allow you to bring your own device. Did they say they couldn't activate it *because it was locked to Republic*, or did they simply say they can't activate it? And no: the link is not relevant here. Unlocking your bootloader is not the same as carrier unlocking.

Comment: they allow bring my own device.  i just need a verizon compatible phone

Comment: Right, and generally that means "Verizon branded". I think the iPhone 6 is an exception, but phones from other networks typically cannot be moved to Verizon like that. So again, did they actually tell you that the phone couldn't be activated because of a network lock? Did they tell you it was a "Verizon compatible" phone? If it's not even compatible then the state of the network lock won't matter.

Comment: to be honest I'm not 100% sure. I guess I'm looking to see if anyone has brought a non-verizon moto x to verizon by unlocking it